# SQLiteException: no such table: APPOINTMENT (code 1) while using Sugar ORM 1.4

Tags: android, sugarorm, android-orm

I want to use **Sugar ORM 1.4**, followed instructions on [This Page](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html), added dependency

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
}
```

Manifest.xml is

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="schedule.db" />
        <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="1" />
        <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="org.ast.labs.schedule.entity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        ...
```

entity is

```
public class Appointment extends SugarRecord{

    private String title;
    private String clientNumber;
    private String clientAddress;

    public Appointment(String title, String clientNumber, String clientAddress) {
        this.title = title;
        this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
        this.clientAddress = clientAddress;
    }
    ....
```

when I try to get List in onCreate() in this way

```
private List<Appointment> mAppointmentList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAppointmentList = Appointment.listAll(Appointment.class);


    TAdapter adapter = new TAdapter(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, mAppointmentList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ...
```

I get error at line *mAppointmentList = Appointment.listAll(Appointment.class);*

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: org.ast.labs.schedule, PID: 22377
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.ast.labs.schedule/org.ast.labs.schedule.activity.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: APPOINTMENT (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM APPOINTMENT
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: APPOINTMENT (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM APPOINTMENT
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:898)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:509)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1346)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1193)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1064)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1270)
       at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:192)
       at com.orm.SugarRecord.listAll(SugarRecord.java:94)
       at org.ast.labs.schedule.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

I'm *NOVICE* to **ORM** on android, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try changing the `android:value="2"` in manifest...and disable instant run

Comment: Still same problem...